# Is there any way to pipe two channels?

Tags: java, nio

I have a `ReadableByteChannel` and a `WritableByteChannel`, now I want to pipe the output from the readable byte channel to the writable byte channel. In other words — when there are bytes available in the readable channel, I want to write them to the writable channel.

Could I do this without a new thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... you can't do it in Java without *any* user-space thread.  It is not possible in standard Java to tell the OS to "replug" two file descriptors and short-circuit the data transfer.

(I'm not aware of any modern mainstream OS that supports this kind of thing.  Though it is not a ridiculous idea.  If anyone knows of an example of an OS with this kind opf functionality, please comment ...)

However, if you use the `SelectableChannel` and `Selector` APIs, a thread can intersperse the "piping" with doing other things, including other (selector-based) I/O on other channels.